# Insert negative values into mysql database?

Tags: mysql, sql

My question is very simple, is it recommended to insert negative values into database?

My field has type INT as integer and I can put numbers like (-20, -30, -33), but it is recommended?

I need more subtraction operations, is this better to do with mysql or php? In PHP case I can insert all values as positive.

Comment: why minus, this is not spam...

Comment: I didnt downvote, but the problem isn't the spam, is the question doesn't have much sense. By definition INT can store from `-2^31 (-2,147,483,648) to 2^31-1 (2,147,483,647)` so your question isnt clear why is that a problem

Comment: I know that, but I'm interested to get informations from excperienced people, how safe is that and if it is recommended

Comment: It's perfectly safe, and the integer type is meant to handle negatives, if needed. If your integers have negative values then by all means, insert away.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's nothing wrong with having negative numbers in the DB. In general if you have to subtract a lot of numbers I would do it in the db rather than the app